# How can I show multiple events on Calendar from web service in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, jtcalendar

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show multiple events on calendar from web service.I am getting value from 3 web service.I am using JTCalendar. 
My code is like this
In viewDidLoad

```
_calendarManager = [JTCalendarManager new];
_calendarManager.delegate = self;
[self createMinAndMaxDate];
[_calendarManager setMenuView:_calendarMenuView];
[_calendarManager setContentView:_calendarContentView];
[_calendarManager setDate:_todayDate];
```

In viewWillAppear

```
[self serverconnectionScheduleAudit];
[self serverconnectionScheduleKPI];
[self serverconnectionScheduleMeeting];
#pragma mark - CalendarManager delegate
- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    // Today
    if([_calendarManager.dateHelper date:[NSDate date] isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
        dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    // Selected date
    else if(_dateSelected && [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_dateSelected isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){

        if([CheckString isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
           dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
           dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
           dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
           dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
            dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
            dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    }
    // Other month
    else if(![_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_calendarContentView.date isTheSameMonthThan:dayView.date]){
        if([CheckString isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }       
    }
    // Another day of the current month
    else{
        if([CheckString isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else if ([CheckString isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
            dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
    if([self haveEventForDay:dayView.date]){
        dayView.dotView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        dayView.dotView.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar didTouchDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    _dateSelected = dayView.date;
    dayView.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);
    [UIView transitionWithView:dayView
                      duration:.3
                       options:0
                    animations:^{
                        dayView.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                        [_calendarManager reload];
                    } completion:nil];
    if(_calendarManager.settings.weekModeEnabled){
        return;
    }
    if(![_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_calendarContentView.date isTheSameMonthThan:dayView.date]){
        if([_calendarContentView.date compare:dayView.date] == NSOrderedAscending){
            [_calendarContentView loadNextPageWithAnimation];
        }
        else{
            [_calendarContentView loadPreviousPageWithAnimation];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - CalendarManager delegate - Page mangement
// Used to limit the date for the calendar, optional
- (BOOL)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar canDisplayPageWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    return [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:date isEqualOrAfter:_minDate andEqualOrBefore:_maxDate];
}
- (void)calendarDidLoadNextPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    //    NSLog(@"Next page loaded");
}
- (void)calendarDidLoadPreviousPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    //    NSLog(@"Previous page loaded");
}

#pragma mark - Fake data
- (void)createMinAndMaxDate
{
    _todayDate = [NSDate date];
    _minDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:-12];
    _maxDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:12];
}
- (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter
{
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    if(!dateFormatter){
        dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
    }
    return dateFormatter;
}
- (BOOL)haveEventForDay:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSString *key = [[self dateFormatter] stringFromDate:date];

    if(_eventsByDate[key] && [_eventsByDate[key] count] > 0){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)funAddEvents:(NSArray *)arrDate
{
    _eventsByDate = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    for(NSString *strDate in arrDate){

        NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformat setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd"];
        NSDate *myDate = [dateformat dateFromString:strDate];
        NSString *key = [[self dateFormatter] stringFromDate:myDate];

        if(!_eventsByDate[key]){
            _eventsByDate[key] = [NSMutableArray new];
        }

        [_eventsByDate[key] addObject:myDate];

    }
}
```

Connection Methods and Delegate

```
#pragma  mark - Schedule Audit Actitvity
//Connection Method and Delegate...
-(void)serverconnectionScheduleAudit{

    [customActivityIndicator startAnimating];

    int Auditid =[Empid intValue];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<AuditMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<UserId>%d</UserId>"
                             "</AuditMethod>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",Auditid];

    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:ServerString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/AuditMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit);
    if(myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit)
    {
        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataFromServerScheduleAudit=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
#pragma  mark - Schedule Actitvity
//Connection Method and Delegate...
-(void)serverconnectionScheduleKPI{

    int KPI =[Empid intValue];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<KPIMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<UserId>%d</UserId>"
                             "</KPIMethod>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",KPI];

    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:ServerString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/KPIMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI);
    if(myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI)
    {

        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataFromServerScheduleKPI=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}

#pragma  mark - Schedule Actitvity
//Connection Method and Delegate...
-(void)serverconnectionScheduleMeeting{

    int KPI =[Empid intValue];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<MeetingMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<UserId>%d</UserId>"
                             "</MeetingMethod>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",KPI];

    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:ServerString];
    // NSURLRequest *myNSURequestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/MeetingMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting);
    if(myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting)
    {

        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataFromServerScheduleMeeting=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    if(connection == myNSUConnectionObjScheduleAudit)
    {
        loginStatusScheduleAudit = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDataFromServerScheduleAudit mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDataFromServerScheduleAudit length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatusScheduleAudit);
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatusScheduleAudit error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
        recordResultScheduleAudit = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResultScheduleAudit);
        NSDictionary* Address=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
        NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",Address);
        NSDictionary *new =[Address objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
        NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
        NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"Get_Audits_Schedules_UserResponse"];
        NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
        NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"Get_Audits_Schedules_UserResult"];
        NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
        if(LoginResult.count>0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
            NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
            NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
            teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
            NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
            NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            responsedictScheduleAudit = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            ScheduleDatearrayScheduleAudit=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            ScheduleDatearrayScheduleAudit =[responsedictScheduleAudit valueForKey:@"StartDate"];
            CheckString=@"0";

             [self funAddEvents:EndDatearrayScheduleAudit];
        }
    }
    if(connection == myNSUConnectionObjScheduleKPI)
    {
        loginStatusScheduleKPI = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDataFromServerScheduleKPI mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDataFromServerScheduleKPI length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatusScheduleKPI);
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatusScheduleKPI error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
        recordResultScheduleKPI = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResultScheduleKPI);
        NSDictionary* Address=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
        NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",Address);
        NSDictionary *new =[Address objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
        NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
        NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"Get_Kpi_Schedules_UserResponse"];
        NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
        NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"Get_Kpi_Schedules_UserResult"];
        NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
        if(LoginResult.count>0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
            NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
            NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
            teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
            NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
            NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            responsedictScheduleKPI = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            StartDatearrayScheduleKPI =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            StartDatearrayScheduleKPI =[responsedictScheduleKPI valueForKey:@"StartDate"];
           CheckString=@"1";

        [self funAddEvents:EndDatearrayScheduleKPI];
        }
    }
    if(connection == myNSUConnectionObjScheduleMeeting)
    {
        loginStatusScheduleMeeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDataFromServerScheduleMeeting mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDataFromServerScheduleMeeting length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatusScheduleMeeting);
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatusScheduleMeeting error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
        recordResultScheduleMeeting = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResultScheduleMeeting);
        NSDictionary* AddressDict=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
        NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",AddressDict);
        NSDictionary *new =[AddressDict objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
        NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
        NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"Get_Meeting_Schedules_UserResponse"];
        NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
        NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"Get_Meeting_Schedules_UserResult"];
        NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
        if(LoginResult.count>0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
            NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
            NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
            teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
            NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
            NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];

            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            responsedictScheduleMeeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            StartDatearrayScheduleMeeting =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            StartDatearrayScheduleMeeting =[responsedictScheduleMeeting valueForKey:@"StartDate"];

            CheckString=@"2";

             [self funAddEvents:EndDatearrayScheduleMeeting];
        }
    }
    NSMutableArray *arrDates=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrDates addObjectsFromArray:StartDatearrayScheduleKPI];
    [arrDates addObjectsFromArray:ScheduleDatearrayScheduleAudit];
    [arrDates addObjectsFromArray:StartDatearrayScheduleMeeting];
    [self funAddEvents:arrDates];

    [customActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParsing Delegate

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"FillBlocksNew"])
    {
        myDataClassObjScheduleAudit=[[mydata alloc]init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    myMutableStringObjScheduleAudit=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObjScheduleAudit);
    NSData *dataAudit = [myMutableStringObjScheduleAudit dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedictScheduleAudit = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataAudit options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedictScheduleAudit);

    myMutableStringObjScheduleKPI=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObjScheduleKPI);
    NSData *dataKPI = [myMutableStringObjScheduleKPI dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedictScheduleKPI = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataKPI options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedictScheduleKPI);

    myMutableStringObjScheduleMeeting=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObjScheduleMeeting);
    NSData *dataMeeting = [myMutableStringObjScheduleMeeting dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedictScheduleMeeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataMeeting options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedictScheduleMeeting);
}
```

I need to show multiple events like this in the image
[image]

I have write so much code because I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

How can I show this? Did any body done like this.Thanks in Advance!